# Convert NSNumber to CLCoordinate

Tags: objective-c, coordinates, core-location, cllocation

I want to pull a list of coordinates from a database into an array (Before displaying them on a map). however, in the database they are of type Number, and I can't figure out how to convert them to coordinates.

This doesn't work:
Where I have an ATM object (The coordinates are for atm machines) with NSNumbers for latitude and longitude. This is in a loop with index i, in order to pull them out one by one. The atmsArray has already been loaded.

```
ATM *aATM = [self.atmsArray objectAtIndex:i];


CLLocationCoordinate2D coord=[[CLLocationCoordinate2D alloc] initWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees)aATM.Latitude longitude:(CLLocationDegrees)aATM.Longitude];
```

Shows up the errors:
-CLLocationCoordinate2D is not an objectiveC class name or alias
-pointer value used when a floating point value was expected
-pointer value used when a floating point value was expected

I've tried a few different things but can't figure it out. If more information is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 15):

aAtm.Longitude and aAtm.Latitude are NSNumbers which are pointers and as such can't be cast to CLLocationDegrees. You need to use the double values of the NSNumbers.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
coord.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[aATM.Longitude doubleValue];
coord.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[aATM.Latitude doubleValue];
```

[As per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951881/iphone-objective-c-error-pointer-value-used-where-a-floating-point-value-was-e/2951934#2951934)

Answer (score 6):

what you want is this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
coord.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees)aATM.Longitude;
coord.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees)aATM.Latitude;
```